# How to make two functions containing while loops run simultaneously with tkinter (ttk) button

Tags: python, multithreading, lambda, tkinter, ttk

I am currently working on a project with basic robots where I have decided to make the robot move randomly while also playing random notes for random duration, thus composing its own music. I currently have two while loops (One in function1 and another in function2), and I am curious as to how I could get both of these to run at the same time when I press a tkinter (ttk) button on the GUI. I believe this would consist of threading, but I do not have much experience with that, and anything to help me figure it out and get on the right track would be great.

Comment: Anything that runs at same time requires threading (or multiple processes, but don't start there). Finding a basic tutorial on threading and getting to work is where to start.

Comment: In the body of these two loops, does the code take a long time to run? As long as any single note, or any single movement takes perhaps 100ms or less, you don't need threading. The answer to your question depends on what you are actually doing in these other loops.

Answer (score 0):

Here have a

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
import asyncio
from random import random


async def loop1(text: ScrolledText):
    while True:
        text.insert(END, 'loop1\n')
        text.see('end')
        await asyncio.sleep(random())


async def loop2(text: ScrolledText):
    while True:
        text.insert(END, 'loop2\n')
        text.see('end')
        await asyncio.sleep(random())


async def run_tk(root, interval=0.05):
    try:
        while True:
            root.update()
            await asyncio.sleep(interval)
    except TclError as e:
        if "application has been destroyed" not in e.args[0]:
            raise


def main():
    root = Tk()
    text = ScrolledText(root)
    text.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=NW+SE)

    asyncio.ensure_future(loop1(text))
    asyncio.ensure_future(loop2(text))

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(run_tk(root))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

In your application, you would play a note (or a chord) and then wait a certain amount of time, which would be perfect for `asyncio.sleep()`. Usually, in concurrency applications you're waiting on some external resource to provide you with data, and in these scenarios `asyncio` only really works if you have libraries that cooperate with `asyncio` all the way down.  In *your* case, you're controlling the show so asyncio would be perfect for you (assuming your *played note* doesn't block for the duration of the held note; otherwise it won't work, and you'll *have to* use threads).

On the other hand, manually pumping the `tk` event loop like this will definitely raise some eyebrows and probably attract scorn.

If you want to go the threading route, that's fine as well, but make sure you pass all communication between threads and the mainloop through a job `Queue`.  It gets somewhat complex, whereas you could be up and running pretty quickly with `asyncio`.